# SQL server select list of rows with same last action

Tags: php, sql-server

I have table:

```
id | uid | action
-----------------
 1 |  1  |   2
 2 |  3  |   1
 3 |  2  |   2
 4 |  3  |   2
 5 |  1  |   1
```

How can I select uid's with last action for example 1? In this case only last line.

**UPDATE:** As you can see for uid=3 at first we have action=1, then action=2 it menas that uid=3 is not "good" line for us. But for uid=1 last action is 1, so that "good" line.

**UPDATE2**: action=1 is enter and action=2 is exit. Finaly I need to get list of users who in building now, or at least list of last action of every user.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? What field are you using in your ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something: `SELECT uid FROM tbl WHERE action = 1`

Comment: No, @MarkByers is right. SQL does not define an order. There's no way to know what is first or last without an order by. Put a datetime in there and we have a question.

Comment: Sorry, I described question not enought. Will describe in update for question.

Comment: @MarkByers You are right. I think we define `id` filed as default, so didn't write it. Now added.

Comment: You need to put some indicator of the order of action in the table, otherwise most attempts to get will reorder by what's in there which will be uid or action. RowNo() might work, but would be very fragile, and break your functionality if you whispered near it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** I added some explanations at the end of my answer.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(
    id INT, 
    [uid] INT, 
    [action] INT
);

INSERT  @Test(id , [uid] , [action])
SELECT  1 ,  1  ,   2
UNION ALL
SELECT  2 ,  3  ,   1
UNION ALL
SELECT  3 ,  2  ,   2
UNION ALL
SELECT  4 ,  3  ,   2
UNION ALL
SELECT  5 ,  1  ,   1;

DECLARE @last_action INT;
SET     @last_action = 1; --or = 2
SELECT  x.uid
FROM
(
SELECT  t.uid, 
        t.action,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.[uid] ORDER BY t.id DESC) AS RowNum
FROM    @Test t
) x
WHERE   x.RowNum = 1
AND     x.action = @last_action
```

Results:

```
uid         
----------- 
1
```

**Explanations:**
The query from derived table `(...) x` will produce folowing results:

```
id uid action RowNum
-- --- ------ ------
5  1   1      1 <-- last action (1) for uid = 1
1  1   2      2
-- --- ------ ------
3  2   2      1 <-- last action (2) for uid = 2
-- --- ------ ------
4  3   2      1 <-- last action (2) for uid = 3
2  3   1      2
-- --- ------ ------
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it returns not all rows. Is it possible to select just last action for every uid?

Comment: @Narek: What you understand by "all rows"? Please edit your answer by adding the results you need.

Comment: Question upadated. Finaly I need to get  list of user in building (last action is 1).

Comment: So, you need only the values from `uid` column ?

Comment: Now yes, in future I'll add other columns too, but I think it will be easy to add new column into SELECT, right?

Comment: a) Then, you have to change this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...` with this `SELECT x.uid FROM (SELECT ...` b) Yes. – Bogdan Sahlean

Comment: Thank you! Still returns wrong result, but i think it my fault! marking as right answer!

Comment: @Narek: I updated my answer with some explanations for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last line in the table, you can order by the id (which looks like it is incrementing each time for a row).  You could then use TOP 1 to filter 1 row per query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table
WHERE action = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: You missed the where clause. He wants to pass a action Id

Comment: Select Top 1 UID from Table where Action = 1 Order by Id Desc

Comment: @sassyboy - OP edited his post. Question is much clearer.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer dialect, one way (of many)...
- assuming column id defines the order...ascending...
- assuming id is unique, at least for each uid

```
select uid
from (
    select uid, max(id) as lastid
    from t
    group by uid
) l
join t on t.uid = l.uid and t.id = l.lastid
where t.action = 1
```

another way...

```
select uid
from t
where id in (select max(id) from t t2 where t2.uid = t.uid)
    and t.action = 1
```